# TSP: Maximize profit with distance constraint

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm, theory, path-finding, traveling-salesman

To keep it as simple as I can, is there a variation of the TSP where I try to maximize benefit with a limitation on how much I can travel with the requirement I make it back home? (I'm quite rusty on these types of algorithms, perhaps requires DP?)

Assume I can calculate the distance between each node, and each visited node is removed from the list.

I think then it should be directed (as cost may differ on direction) with a cost/benefit ratio as the weights.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: First tip:  EAAITQ (explain any Acronym in the question)

Answer (score 0):

- Run standard TSP
- If total distance less than max DONE
- Run Dijsktra to find distance from home to every vertex
- Remove vertex furthest from home
- LOOP

Comment: can you please give a short explanation about why this process will work?